# post.php AJAX request not being called when publishing post

Tags: hooks, admin, publish

I am using the `transition_post_status` to process a post being published. I was getting inconsistent behaviour between two installations of WordPress, and I have tracked this down to the AJAX calls being made from the post compose page itself.

These are the requests being made when I transition a post from a draft to published on my two installations:

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the AJAX call to post.php is not being made in the second example. It turns out that the global `$post` object is in a different state inside `transition_post_status` hook when being called via post.php, which is why my code only works on the first installation.

What I need to understand is why I have 2 installations of WordPress that are seemingly doing different things when publishing a post.

Both installations are running 5.7.2, and are stock aside from the 1 plugin that I am working on, which is the same on both installations.

Can anyone shed any light on why two different installations are triggering different AJAX calls when publishing a post?

Comment: That screenshot doesn't help much.. And what's your code? Have you also checked the hook [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/)?

Comment: My code is irrelevant at this point and these screenshots are the only ones I’m able to provide for the issue I’m trying to solve, which is to understand why two different installations are making different AJAX calls when publishing a post.

Comment: Well, there could be many reasons... And if you could inspect the network/XHR requests and check the request and (server's) response data, headers, etc., then I believe you'd get the answer.

Comment: Well, not really? Inspecting the requests and data and headers doesn't tell me _why_ WordPress didn't even make the second request, does it? The output of the first request is the same on both installations, a JSON response of the post - but this doesn't explain why one installation makes a further request to post.php and the other does not. Do you have anything constructive to suggest other than blindly checking responses and headers for nothing specific?

Comment: Something constructive? 1) Share the XHR request/response data (with dummy data being replaced or maybe blurred if sharing a screenshot). 2) Share your code and we might be able to reproduce the issue in question. 3) List the exact steps you took on the post editing screen. 4) Did you use the classic editor or Gutenberg; if not, which installation uses which editor? 5) Did you try with another browser, a new window/tab? So I'm saying, provide as much details as possible and we might come up with a better constructive comments for you.

Comment: * "with dummy data" - I meant, sensitive/private data, if any. "or Gutenberg; if not, which" - "or Gutenberg, and which".

Comment: 1) This is the AJAX response from the first request to /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id> - https://imgur.com/a/swLdM6J - identical on both sites other than obvious difference in post title/dates etc. 2) My plugin is disabled currently, this is core WP I'm trying to debug. 3) Have a post in draft, publish it - that's it. 4) Both sites are stock as I said, so both using Gutenberg. 5) Yes, regardless of browser, the second installation does not make the AJAX call to post.php

Comment: Try debugging on a test installation - start a post and save it as a draft, then publish it and see what AJAX calls are made. I am expecting to see a call to /wp-json/wp/v2/posts/<id>, and then a call to post.php. Do you see both requests, or only the first?

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details, but I was particularly asking for the XHR request made to *and* response received from `post.php`. Can I see those data?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the calls to `/wp-admin/post.php` are due to there being custom meta boxes on the post compose page. The initial XHR request is to the WP API to save the post, but then additional XHR calls are made to process the meta boxes. This then re-saves the post, and calls the `transition_post_status` hook again.

When the API first saves the post, the status is going from `draft` to `publish`, and on the secondary calls, if they run, it is going from `publish` to `publish` - that in itself makes sense.

My specific problem was that I was calling some code that required `$post` to be globalised, which was only the case in the second XHR call, leading to inconsistent behaviour when the hook which called that code was being run twice - one when `$post` was globalised and one when it was not.

Comment: "custom meta boxes on the post compose page" - which do not actually exist on a stock setup of WordPress. But I did forget about meta boxes, maybe because that's an old thing just as the `admin-ajax.php`.. And I'm a bit curious about that "calling some code that required `$post` to be globalised", but anyway, +1 for your efforts or the helpful findings. 

Comment: Yeah, I hadn't noticed the 1 plugin I had (which was the only non-stock thing) was adding it, and wasn't expecting it to send off a whole other request. The wider issue was I needed to use the global `$post` in my `the_content` hook and I returned early if `$post` didn't exist, instead of returning `$content`. The meta box XHR request globalised `$post` so masked this issue in my `the_content` callback. Is why I was more trying to understand why the `post.php` request was even being made, as once I knew why that request was there I could figure out what to do with my specific code.

Comment: I see. But, "I returned early if `$post` didn't exist" - I hope you were not referring to something like `return;`, because `the_content` filters should always return the content. Also, in the question, you stated that you're accessing the *global* `$post` from within the `transition_post_status` hook, so (I don't know why you need to access that global `$post`, but) in case you're not aware, the hook actually has a third parameter (`$post`) which contains the correct data of the post being saved.

Comment: Yes, I was just doing `return;` inside `the_content` which was the root cause of my issue for the reason you mentioned, however that mistake was masked by the fact `$post` _was_ globally available inside `the_content` when the XHR request to `post.php` was made, as it was globalised before `transition_post_status` ran, so my `the_content` code continued on and returned content further on in the code. So it was only due to the `post.php` request globalising `$post` that my `the_content` code ever worked at all, and the bug surfaced when the `post.php` XHR request wasn't made.